# Password for ec2-user on AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I am trying to run `$ sudo su` in the terminal of AWS Cloud9. I get prompted for the password for the ec2-user. Any ideas what this might be?

Might be worth noting that prior to coming up against this issue, when trying to `yum install` a package, I got 'packages excluded due to repository priority protections' so I ran `yum erase yum-plugin-priorities` as per https://serverfault.com/questions/312472/what-does-that-mean-packages-excluded-due-to-repository-priority-protections (I'm fairly sure I had to do that with `sudo` but wasn't prompted for the password).

Comment: I think when you login first time you have manually set the password by typing the __passwd__ and then type sudo su  or check this if fails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596108/how-do-i-change-my-password-in-linux

Comment: Thank you @babygame0ver I started a new AWS cloud 9 environment and was able to change the ec2-user password with `sudo passwd ec2-user`. But when I then ran `sudo yum install httpie` and entered my password at the prompt, I got 'Sorry, user ec2-user is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/yum install httpie' as root on ip-10-0-0-32.' and didn't feel so super :(

Comment: By default EC2 instances do not have a root password. Was this setup as an `EC@` environment? i.e. you let AWS Cloud9 setup the EC2 instance for you. 

Which region are you working in?

Answer (score 7):

First you need to set your password using command

```
$ sudo passwd ec2-user
```

Then you can use the new password where ever its required

Answer (score 1):

In the cloud9 (terminal) you have to change the users password with:

```
$ sudo passwd ec2-user
Changing password for user ec2-user.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem which trying to install `homebrew` on my ec2@Cloud9 Env.

When requested for password, I didn't place any let the program wait for a while after which I could see the package `homebrew` got installed.

Comment: Because it is not a direct answer to the question this observation would be more helpful as a comment.

Answer (score -3):

Use "sudo passwd root" or "sudo passwd"

Comment: It's asking for the user's password, so how will setting a password for root help?

Comment: There are 3 users in AWS-CLOUD9: 1.- ec2-user, 2.- root, 3.- ubuntu / amazon-linux. Setting the root password with the `sudo passwd root` command allows ec2-user to execute the `sudo yum install httpie` command, set the root password, it also allows to execute the `sudo yum install httpie` command from user Ubuntu / Amazon-linux . The default user for AWS CLOUD9 is Ubuntu / Amazon-linux.

Comment: sudo asks for the current user's password. there is no need to set root's password to use sudo.